# Draw TextBox border as in Vista / 7

Tags: c#, textbox, styles, aero

In Windows.Forms, I was not able to reproduce the exact same TextBox border as you see it in Vista / 7 Aero. All I get is a gray rectangle instead the slightly sunken gray / blue 3d border. I tried the following methods with no success:

- VisualStyleRenderer class
- TextBoxRenderer class
- Control.DrawToBitmap()
- P/Invoke with UxTheme and friends
- Drawing RichTextBox elements instead of TextBox ones

This problem has already been discussed here but with no solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/winforms/thread/46e66852-b52e-420d-8fe0-b717f86ecb18

It looks like there's no obvious solution for this problem.
Does anyone know how to draw the exact same border as in Aero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not going to happen for you.

I *think* the `VisualStyleRenderer`, including the `TextBoxRenderer`, were more meant for the XP themes.

Even the `Control.DrawToBitmap(...)` function *magically* draws a different version from what is on the screen.

I don't have the canonical answer for this, but it's most likely a result of Microsoft moving on with WPF and leaving behind the WinForm controls with those visual themes half-baked.

The only answer to this question is to use WPF or use a 3rd party system like DevExpress (which support custom themes) if you need to "theme" all of your controls.

Comment: I feared I had to switch to WPF for this. However, the project in which we need this is pretty huge and completely Win.Forms based, so we can't switch to WPF yet.