# Make a border of disabled NumericUpDown same to TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

[image]

Is it possible to achieve not by subclassing a NumericUpDown?

Comment: **NO** What's wrong with subclassing?

Comment: It's possible to achieve the visual effect without subclassing, but it requires a dummy textbox.  When 'disabling' the NumericUpDown you would hide the NumericUpDown and show the dummy textbox which overlays exactly on top the NumericUpDown.

Comment: @aush using the so-called `Dummy textbox` is much worse than subclassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible. I tried to retrieve a real Vista / 7 textbox border for a custom control, but all methods I tried didn't work.

The only solution is a dummy textbox around a borderless numeric up down (I hope it's possible to hide the border of it).

Also see my question: [Draw TextBox border as in Vista / 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182524/draw-textbox-border-as-in-vista-7)